# JavaScript If-Statement Proved True But Outputs False

Tags: javascript, if-statement, p5.js

I am learning JavaScript by programming my first game (a simple laser-mirror-type game). The game operates in a grid and I want to determine if a cell holds an obstacle or not. So I call this function:

```
function updateGrid () {
for (let i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            for (let o = 0; o < obstacles.length; o++) {
                if (grid[i][j].x === obstacles[o].x && grid[i][j].y === obstacles[o].y) {
                    grid[i][j].obstacle = true;
                } else if (grid[i][j].x != obstacles[o].x && grid[i][j].y != obstacles[o].y) {
                    //grid[i][j].obstacle = false;
                }
            }
            for (let m = mirrors.length - 1; m >= 0; m--) {
                if (grid[i][j].x + cellOffset.x== mirrors[m].x && grid[i][j].y + cellOffset.y == mirrors[m].y) {
                    grid[i][j].mirror = true;
                } else {
                    grid[i][j].mirror = false;
                }
            }
            if (grid[i][j].x + cellOffset.x == target.x && grid[i][j].y + cellOffset.y == target.y) {
                grid[i][j].target = true;
            } else {
                grid[i][j].target = false;
            }
            if (grid[i][j].x == laserPen.x && grid[i][j].y + (rowH / 2) - (cellOffset.y / 4) == laserPen.y) {
                grid[i][j].pen = true;
            } else {
                grid[i][j].pen = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However the if-statement that determines if the cell contains an obstacle, seems to not work.

This works (sets **grid[ i ][ j ].obstacle** to *true*):

```
for (let o = 0; o < obstacles.length; o++) {
    if (grid[i][j].x === obstacles[o].x && grid[i][j].y === obstacles[o].y) {
            grid[i][j].obstacle = true;
    } else if (grid[i][j].x != obstacles[o].x && grid[i][j].y != obstacles[o].y) {
        //grid[i][j].obstacle = false;
    }
}
```

This does not (sets **grid[ i ][ j ].obstacle** to *false*):

```
for (let o = 0; o < obstacles.length; o++) {
    if (grid[i][j].x === obstacles[o].x && grid[i][j].y === obstacles[o].y) {
            grid[i][j].obstacle = true;
    } else if (grid[i][j].x != obstacles[o].x && grid[i][j].y != obstacles[o].y) {
        grid[i][j].obstacle = false;
    }
}
```

I actually added the else-if just for safety, but it failed to work with a simple else-statement as well.

**I am using the p5.js library and any insight into what is happening here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!**

Comment: When i was coding a game like this with a grind system i encountered the same prob. I resolved it by trying to add 1 to indexes / removing one. Don't miss that index start to 0 :)

Comment: what if in your if-else statements, 1 condition is true and 1 is false ? what would happen then ?

Comment: It's going to be pretty hard to help you with the information you've given us. Can you please [debug your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging)? That link is for Processing, but you can use your [developer tools](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) to do the same thing in P5.js. What is the value of `i`, `j` and `grid[i][j]` on that line? What is the value of `o` and `obstacles[o]`? You have to narrow the problem down and then post a [mcve] using hard-coded values wherever possible. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, I hardcoded values in for the if statements within my developer console but to no avail. Eventually I went back to console.logging all of the values being read. This lead me to realize that if obstacles[0] proved true for grid[2][2] but then obstacles[1] proved false for grid[2][2], this would lead to grid[2][2].obstacle being false. I am still not sure why hardcoding in the console didn't work, but luckily I found my answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug after some testing. I was iterating through all the obstacles on the same grid cell (i.e. test obstacles[0] for grid[2][2], test obstacles[1] for grid[2][2]). This meant that if the first obstacle in the array proved true, but the others proved false, the overall grid[2][2].obstacle would become false. Or to map it visually:

```
grid[2][1] ...
grid[2][2].obstacle = true!
grid[2][2].obstacle = false.
grid[2][2].obstacle = false.
grid[2][3] ...
```

Output:

```
grid[2][2].obstacle is false :(
```